# Allow App Transport Security for radio streams with AVMediaPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-transport-security

I'm currently working on a simple radio player app. Since the radio streams from the radio stations usually come via http, the App Transport Security does not allow this. I've already tried adding keys like `Allows Arbitrary Loads for Media` to the property list, the Transport Security app rejects the requests coming from the AVMediaPlayer. Is there a way at all, or do you have to release all Domins individually?

Here is my Property List:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMediaUsageDescription</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSATSExceptionServiceType</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSThirdPartyMediaStreaming</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict/>
```

Here is the error message I get:

> Task <2055AEDE-05A5-46FC-9B7B-926B6DD08F52>.<2> finished with error [-1022] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://sunshinelive.hoerradar.de/sunshinelive-live-mp3-hq, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://sunshinelive.hoerradar.de/sunshinelive-live-mp3-hq, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "LocalDataTask <2055AEDE-05A5-46FC-9B7B-926B6DD08F52>.<2>"
> ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <2055AEDE-05A5-46FC-9B7B-926B6DD08F52>.<2>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003416e50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}}